# Button that starts and stops the movement of the object

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create the button that can do the following:

1)If you click it, the button starts the movement of some object

2)If you click it again, it stops the movement

So, I have this object:

`<div id="block">I'm green square</div>`

And the button

`<button onclick="movement()">Movement</button>`

What I tried to do is to create a global variable `let positionChange = false;` 
and in the function at first to change the value of `positionChange` and then complete the following algorithm.

```
const movement = function() {
    const block = document.getElementById('block');
    let left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block,null).getPropertyValue('left'));
    const width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block,null).getPropertyValue('width'));
    if (positionChange)
    {
        positionChange = false;
    }
    else
    {
        positionChange = true;
    }
    while (positionChange)
    {
        if (left < 1000 - width)
        {
            left+=20;
            block.style.left = left+'px';
        }
        else
        {
            block.style.left = '0px';
        }
    }   
}
```

But, it doesn't work. So, what should I do?

---

After comment I tried to remake my script. Not I have function `changeX` that moves my object. And function `movement` has to start/stop the `changeX`.

```
const changeX = function(){
    const block = document.getElementById('block');
    let left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block,null).getPropertyValue('left'));
    const width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(block,null).getPropertyValue('width'));
    if (left < 1000 - width)
    {
        left+=20;
        block.style.left = left+'px';
    }
    else
    {
        block.style.left = '0px';
    }
}
const movement = function() {
        if (positionChange === false)
{
    //alert('Now true');
    positionChange = true;
    const timerId = setInterval(changeX,1);
}
else
{
    //alert('Now false');
    positionChange = false;
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
};
```

Now the button can start, but can't stop the movement

Comment: First, this should be handled with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` instead of a loop, so the UI won't be blocked, which prevents you from pressing the button the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take your timerId to the global scope.
You are declaring the timerId inside the if scope, so inside the else scope, the timerId is not defined.

You can do something like this:

```
let positionChange = false;
let timerId; // On the global scope

const ToggleMovment = () => {
    if (positionChange === false)
    {
        //alert('Now true');
        positionChange = true;
        timerId = setInterval(startMoving,1);
    }
    else
    {
        positionChange = false;
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code snippet doesn't tell me much about positionChange or widthChange (like where they come from, their scope, etc), but also you have what looks like a blocking loop, in the while(widthChange) statement. This is a closed loop and the value of widthChange unlikely to ever get changed!

Comment: I'm sorry. widthChange had to be positionChange. I corrected it

Comment: It wasn't me. I even can't still vote with my reputation

Comment: I understand. No worries. Just looking for why... :)